# Windows Store app local folder data lost when running WACK?

Tags: windows-store-apps, packaging

My first Windows Store App is almost ready to be uploaded. It passed the Windows App Certification Kit test on my machine. However if I "build packages to upload to Windows Store", it fails the test due to "Crashes and hangs". I found out that the WACK deletes my package folder before running the test, and because the app needs to load data from there upon start, it will probably not find it and thus hangs.

My questions are:

1. What happens to the files in my Local folder (i.e. C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\packageName\LocalState) when the app is packaged?
2. If I need to read and write data from files upon app start, where should I keep these files?

Thank you a lot for your time!

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, WACK 3.4.

Here is some code that runs when my app starts, I try to deserialize an existing file in the Local folder:

```
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFolder demoFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Demos", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFolder gameRecordFolder = await demoFolder.CreateFolderAsync("GameRecords", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        string filename = gameRecName+".xaml";
        StorageFile gameFile = await gameRecordFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);

        GameRecord g;
        using (Stream fileStream = await gameFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameRecord));
            g = (GameRecord)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
```

Comment: I dont see how this code would work the first time it is run.  You create a demo and GameRecord folder and expect a file to be there.  You need to check if the file exists and if it does not create it with code or copy it from a resource included with the app to the folder.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed the local folder to be included with the app. Maybe that's it.

Comment: No the local folder will not be automatically included

Comment: Meanwhile I was trying to include the demo file in the package, although I added it to the project and changed its extension from .xaml to something else, it is not installed in the bin\Release folder and I cannot retrieve it with " Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation". How can I include it in my package as a resource and retrieve it like you said?

Comment: Thanks Ken. I think I found the problem: I need to set the file's build action in Visual Studio. Anyone please let me know if I miss anything.